# CSS Media Queries, Opera and Firefox trouble

Tags: firefox, css, opera, media-queries

I'm using the **Ubuntu** font for my website and Opera doesn't render the page when I do:

```
html {
  font-family: 'Ubuntu', sans-serif;
}
```

So I have to do css media queries:

```
/*Chrome*/
@media not all and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {  
  html,
  button,
  input,
  select,
  textarea {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu',sans-serif;
  } 
}

/*Safari*/
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
  html,
  button,
  input,
  select,
  textarea {
    font-family: 'Ubuntu',sans-serif;
  } 
}

/*Opera*/
@media not screen and (1) {
  html,
  button,
  input,
  select,
  textarea {
    font-family: sans-serif;
  } 
}
```

The problem is that now I don't know how to implement this for Firefox. And searching the internet hasn't given me an answer.

Any ideas?

Kind regards.

Comment: Some info on this problem here which may help: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18972/why-wont-opera-let-me-use-the-ubuntu-font

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this way:

```
@media not all and (-moz-windows-compositor) { ... }
```

Take a look here for more information: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Media_queries

Comment: Do you have an idea on how to implement this for IE? Thank you.

Comment: Unfortunately, media query is not supported in Internet Explorer 8 or older.

Answer (score 0):

With the media query `-moz-windows-compositor` you're just targeting Firefox on Windows/Linux, for various other OSs (in case you have problems with the font there as well) you'd need

```
 @media not all and (-moz-device-pixel-ratio) {…}
```